# User logged out automatically when browser is closed when using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise gem for authentication of my rails application. The issue is that the user gets logged out when he closes the browser. I want the user to be logged in until he clicks the log out button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding a 3 line code to my **user.rb** file :)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :rememberable
  ....     
  def remember_me
    true
  end
end
```